# MySQL Querying Aggregate of Non Overlapping Dates

Tags: mysql, date, stream, aggregate-functions, overlapping

Let's assume that the following data stream is given:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
  id bigint(20),
  start_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
  end_datetime DATETIME
);
```

**1. The First Data Stream**

```
INSERT INTO reservation (id, start_datetime, end_datetime) VALUES
(1, '2015-05-01 00:00:00', '2015-05-03 00:00:00'),
(2, '2015-05-02 00:00:00', '2015-05-05 00:00:00'),
(3, '2015-05-03 00:00:00', '2015-05-04 00:00:00'),
(4, '2015-05-05 00:00:00', '2015-05-07 00:00:00');
```

For the first insert values id = 1, 2, 3, and 4. I need to get the "Total Reservation Index". The expected result will be:

```
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | Total Reservation Index | start_datetime      | end_datetime        |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 |                      2  | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 |
|    4 |                      2  | 2015-05-05 00:00:00 | 2015-05-07 00:00:00 |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**2. The Second Data Stream**

```
INSERT INTO reservation (id, start_datetime, end_datetime) VALUES
(5, '2015-05-04 00:00:00', null),
(6, '2015-05-02 00:00:00', null),
(7, '2015-05-05 00:00:00', null),
(8, '2015-05-01 00:00:00', null);
```

You will notice that end_datetime is `NULL`. The business logic for table reservation means, the reservation is opened forever. So, by using the same query like the first data stream, it should result as follow:

```
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | Total Reservation Index | start_datetime      | end_datetime        |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 |                      2  | 2015-05-01 00:00:00 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 |
|    5 |                      5  | 2015-05-04 00:00:00 | 2015-05-08 00:00:00 |
+------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Notice that the `id = 4` is changed to `id = 5`. Thus, the total index if we do SUM operation for "Total Reservation Index" column is 7 (or 2 + 5).

**3. The Third Data Stream**

```
INSERT INTO reservation (id, start_datetime, end_datetime) VALUES
(9, '2015-05-04 00:00:00', '2015-05-04 00:00:00'),
(10, '2015-05-05 00:00:00', '2015-05-07 00:00:00'),
(11, '2015-05-01 00:00:00', '2015-05-07 00:00:00');
```

For the third data stream, we will use the same query.. the expected result will be the same result as the second data stream. It will return `2 rows => id 1 and 5`.

**4. The Fourth Data Stream**

```
INSERT INTO reservation (id, start_datetime, end_datetime) VALUES
(12, '2015-05-07 00:00:00', null);
```

In the forth data stream, it will have the same result like the second data stream. It will return `2 rows => id 1 and 5`.

**Current Attempt**

My current attempt is by using this

```
select id, datediff('2015-05-08', start_datetime) as 'Total Reservation Index', start_datetime, end_datetime from reservation where start_datetime < end_datetime or end_datetime is null and start_datetime >= '2015-05-01' and end_datetime <= '2015-05-08' order by start_datetime asc;
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the confusion of '2015-05-08'. '2015-05-08' comes from the end filter date. Like I ask in the question below. It does have filter start_date and end_date. Hence, the value of '2015-05-08' **intended** to trick/replace the `NULL` value in `end_datetime` column.
In addition, for any given `NULL` data in `end_datetime` column it will replace the end filter date. The end filter date could be '2015-05-10' or '2015-05-11' but of course it will expect different query results.

However, the query above did not go as expected. Since I need to exclude the overlapping dates and also I need to filter based on start_datetime and end_datetime.

To illustrate the overlapping dates, I have included the images below.

[image]

The **YELLOW** block represents the data has proper datetime value in `end_datetime` column.

The **ORANGE** block represents the data has `NULL` value in `end_datetime` column.

Now, What would the SQL to achieve the expected result for the first, second, third, and fourth data stream? (Note: It must be the same SQL query for all data streams. Since it does not make sense for every data stream to use different SQL query)

Comment: You lost me in the first 3 "code sample" blocks; it is not clear how you are expecting/calculating `Total Reservation Index`. In the next two blocks, I am at a loss as to where the value `2015-05-08 00:00:00` even came from.

Comment: Great amount of data, and examples, but what does `Total Reservation Index` even mean? Utterly confused by what you are trying to do.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. How do you get '2' in each row for the first group??

Comment: Also, why are ids 2 and 3 excluded?

Comment: @McAdam331 because the dates are overlapping with id 1.

Comment: @Arth Sorry if it confuses you, 'Total Reservation Index' does calculate the difference between end_date and start_date. The expected query and the attempted query should explain well.

Comment: The attempted query does not explain it, as you've hardcoded 2015-05-08.

Comment: @Uueerdo 2015-05-08 00:00:00 comes from the end filter date.

Comment: @McAdam331 I have added further explanation. The '2015-05-08' comes from the filter (see my sentences about query filters) and it does represent the value to trick the `NULL` data in `end_datetime` column

Comment: @McAdam331  Please see the explanation of '2015-05-08' value in the question again. I have edited once more time to clear up the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: You are not being clear, either about SQL updates/queries or whatever you are doing with them. Examples are no use unless you say what they are examples of. You need to use language to explain when an arbitrary row of values should appear in an update or query result given what rows appear in the base tables. Apparently it has something to do with intervals overlapping--say what you mean. Also, *what about* these "data streams", and what do you even *mean* by "data stream"? And what is your "current attempt" an attempt *at*? Don't just throw out a bunch of fragments.